# QT show "RTTI symbol not found for class" but work fine

Tags: qt, c++11, lambda, smart-pointers

I test shared_ptr and lambda deleter as follow code.
It's work fine. but when debug it, showing:

```
RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::_Sp_counted_deleter<cls*, main::{lambda(cls*)#1}, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>'
```

any problem with my code?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class cls{
public:
    void test(){
        cout << "ok\n";
    }

    virtual ~cls(){
       cout << "~cls()\n";
    }
};

typedef shared_ptr<cls> stptr;

int main(){
    auto del = [](cls* p){delete(p);};
    stptr p = stptr(new cls, del);
    p->test();
    return 0;
}
```

screen shot:
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

Code looks good.

I encountered the same problem with GDB (the default debugger in QtCreator when compiling with GCC). I think this is a problem of GDB when it looks for RTTI of a type where a lambda is involved. 
With Clang and LLDB (available in "kits" if Clang is installed on your system) I don't see this problem.